Tracking Multiple Button Clicks in A/B Testing with Firebase
I'm currently setting up A/B tests in Firebase to determine which variant of a button leads to more clicks per user. While I can currently track whether a button is clicked at all, I need to capture how many times each button is clicked by the same user within each variant.
Could anyone advise how to modify my Firebase setup to count multiple clicks on a button during an A/B test? Any tips or code snippets would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!


Firebase UI - You can define "Goals" before running AB test Experiment. These goals can't be updated once AB test runs.
If your AB test is running, you can query this data in Google BigQuery - basically you can query your experiment data by assigned AB test variant to the user. The integration between Firebase/Google Analytics 4 (GA4) and BigQuery won't backfill data, so if integration hasn't been enabled, your historic data is only available in Firebase/GA4 UI. Data is being export to BigQuery since the day you setup integration.

